# Rails 5 Search Facets Filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, elasticsearch, solr, rubygems

I would like to add the ability to filter records using facets. I know Elastic Search can help with it, but I don't want to setup an elastic search server. I am looking for a really easy solution. I would like to have the search and facets filters run on Postgres and Ruby on Rails 5.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to setup ElasticSearch/Solr server,

[FortyFacets](https://github.com/fortytools/forty_facets) appears to be a very good option. It lets you easily build faceted search based on fields of your models (see [Active Record model pattern](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html)).